# Объединить синонимичные метки [ассоциативный-массив], [dictionary], [map] и др

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [ассоциативный-массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2) - 0 вопросов;
- [словари](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8) - 30 вопросов;
- [dictionary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) - 8 вопросов;
- [dictionaries](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) - 41 вопрос;
- [map](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) - 93 вопроса.

Эти метки нужно объединить в [ассоциативный-массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2), в связи с прояснившейся смысловой нагрузкой метки [map](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) (слияние в пользу которой видится мне не самым удачным решением).

Comment: уж лучше, наверное, у нас использовать русский вариант

Comment: @mymedia боюсь, что [tag:словарь] будет сильно ассоциироваться у русскоязычных пользователей с прямым смыслом слова, а не с техническим, которым здесь эта метка нагружается.

Comment: Прямым, это каким? Кстати, как по поводу вопросов, относящихся к словарям, которые списки слов. Думаю, это могло бы быть онтопиком на SO, если обсуждаются словари для программ проверки правописания или для перебора паролей.

Comment: @mymedia прямой смысл слова "словарь": https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Словарь

Comment: И вот как странно получается: [tag:map] — структура данных, но [tag:maps] — карты местности

Comment: вообще-то я туда заглянул, прежде чем отправлять свой комментарий с переспросом. В любом случае, это получается уже не синонимы, несмотря на то, что у нас они используются в таком качестве.

Comment: Возможно, вместо объединения стоит вообще уничтожить эти метки…

Comment: Русский вариант, насколько мне известно, [tag:ассоциативный-массив]. Но там пусто :)

Comment: А в заголовке не словарь, а множество. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю объединить [dictionary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), [dictionaries](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionaries) и [словари](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8). Основной сделать [словари](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8).

Остальные — не трогать, так как по метке [ассоциативный-массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2) вопросов нет, а по метке [map](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/map) почти все вопросы по картам.